# How to edit a file inside a zip package submitted from HTML form

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to setup a html form that will take a file from a zip archive and edit it (change a few variables value) on submit.

so here's the process:

user inputs details into the html form

a copy of a zip archive with a cofig.php will be copied into a temp folder

config.php will be extracted from the zip

once config.php has been extracted, the config.php in the zip will be deleted (ready for replacement)

the config.php that gets extracted needs to be edited

contents of config.php:

```
<?

$varible1 = "data_from_html_form";

$varible2 = "data_from_html_form";

$varible3 = "some_value";

//etc etc....

?>
```

the file will then be saved and placed back into the temporary zip archive ready to be distributed to the user.

All i need to know is how to edit the config.php and the variables in it.

Comment: Is it okay if they just edit the source of config.php or do you want some sort of abstracted GUI?

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. I'm afraid i need this all to be automatic. Some of the users will get lost, which can be frustrating. So id just prefer to get it all done myself without hassling them. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a file with [`fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to read your file into an array of strings, process it as you need (add/modify/remove), than use [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to save it back to file.

```
$contents = file('*your filename*');

foreach ($contents as $line) {
    //perform alterations;
}

unset ($contents[2]); //remove line 2;
$contents[] = "aaaa"; //append "aaaa" to the end of the file

file_put_contents('*filename*', $contents);
```

You can call `file_put_contents` with one-dimension array as second argument, but check if all newlines are still present in new file. If they are disappeared, use `implode("\n",$contents)` instead of just `$contents`.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. That looks about right. But i'm still not sure how id change the variables value without completely writing them all up again. So I have no idea what should go between "foreach ($contents as $line) {" and "}". Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think some regex-based processing will do the trick. As a simple approach you could split your strings by `=` and have name on the left side and value on the right side (if you are not using arrays of cource). See [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-split.php) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you're trying to do is open a file, prepaid a string, and write back to the file:

```
$phpfile = file_get_contents($filename);
$phpfile .= $prependdata;
file_put_contents($phpfile, $filename);
```

If that's not what you're trying to do, forgive my misunderstanding.

Note: not sure on the order of arguments, and I don't have time at the right now to look.  You should be able to find that stuff on php.net.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. But thats not what I'm looking for. I need to change a variables value inside a temp file. That code looks like it writes stuff onto the .php file but not changing any variables value. I've looked all over php.net and have got lost many times. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look here http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php. Look at the examples. You will need the zip extension installed though http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Comment: hey, thats not what I'm looking for. I just need to change the variables in the config.php. I'm not worried about all the zip archive stuff at this moment. thanks anyway.